# Neutrino not transforming spread operator

Tags: javascript, babeljs, spread-syntax, neutrino

I'm new to Neutrino, but I have my project working for everything but the object spread operator `let bar = {...foo, x: 1}` yields `Module parse failed: Unexpected token` over and over.
I'm already using the react preset/middleware, but I went ahead and manually added the transform plugin as well when the preset alone didn't work.  Here is my .neutrinorc.js config:

```
module.exports = {
    options: {
        mains: {
            index: 'index',
            login: 'login'
        }
    },
    use: [
        ['@neutrinojs/react', { html: { title: 'SST' }}],
        ['@neutrinojs/dev-server', { port: 1332 }],
        '@neutrinojs/mocha',
        neutrino => {
            // access the Neutrino API    
            neutrino.config.resolve.modules.add('node_modules');

            neutrino.config.module
            .rule('compile')
              .use('babel')
                .tap(options => {
                    options.plugins.push(require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread'))
                    return options;
                });
         }
    ]
};
```

Comment: You are correct in that the react preset already comes with the rest/spread transform. Could you share a repo or test case that replicates this?

Comment: I think something about the way I set up my aliases in my project is preventing Neutrino from babelifying my dependencies?  I've recreated the problem in this repo: https://github.com/DaveWelling/sampleLernaProblem.git

Comment: Nope.  Even if I point directly at the dependency module, it won't babelify it.  `import Socks from 'pocdep/src/ragnarok/argyleSocks';` just gives me an `Unexpected token`.  I guess I need to explicitly include the dependency in my babel config.  This threw me off because I've been using NWB and didn't have to do that, but I remember this is the way it was before I used NWB.